# Circle ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, geometry

I am using Picasso to set circle image sources to my ImageView and it is working fine. The problem is that I am using `android:background=?selectableItemBackground`, and the ripple effect (or the touch effect for previous version) fill the square (because the imageView is really a square, only the source is a circle). Can I change this square to circle?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: there are a few implementation of round imageviews out there

Comment: I would highly recommend checking out the following libraries: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: I tried CircularImageView and has the same problem that the normal imageview + picasso. The circleview is a square. Do you know if the other will have the same problem?

Comment: @Dahnark in some libraries like I think RoundedImageView, you have to specify the radius or the amount of circle, and if you don't the image appears like a normal square imageview

Comment: How I change the radius? for example, this is already implemented: https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView